# React Native build fails : File exceeds size limit of 2147483647

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to build an apk of my app.

This is an app which contains video assets (~3Go of assets). I don't need to upload it on the Play Store (I'll manually install the apk on a set of devices).

When I run `./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace`, I get the following error:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to read zip file '/Users/enguerran/Sites/pinail-app/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/release/processReleaseResources/out/resources-release.ap_'.
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$onEach$1.invoke(_Sequences.kt:1262)
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)
        at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
        at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:153)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:647)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:677)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:668)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:140)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:115)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:32)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:404)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file '/Users/enguerran/Sites/pinail-app/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/release/processReleaseResources/out/resources-release.ap_'.
        at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:461)
        at com.android.builder.files.RelativeFiles.fromZip(RelativeFiles.java:120)
        at com.android.builder.files.IncrementalRelativeFileSets.fromZip(IncrementalRelativeFileSets.java:102)
        at com.android.builder.files.IncrementalRelativeFileSets.fromZip(IncrementalRelativeFileSets.java:80)
        at com.android.builder.files.IncrementalRelativeFileSets.fromZipsAndDirectories(IncrementalRelativeFileSets.java:280)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:513)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.lambda$doFullTaskAction$3(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:399)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:121)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:110)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File exceeds size limit of 2147483647.
        at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:442)
        ... 8 more
```

How can I increase this limit?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple configuration option to get around this. If you look at the [ZFile.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apkzlib/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/java/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/zip/ZFile.java) source, you'll see that the constructor explicitly checks that the filesize is not `> Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Given the above and that you are planning to manually deploy the app, one option might be to deploy the video assets to the device's filesystem in a known location that the app can access instead of packaged as a resource in the APK.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do that using React Native, but I suppose that will change my app code?

Comment: React Native is well outside my wheelhouse, so I have little idea how much change it would require to your app code. I imagine there would be at least a little. Another option is to reduce the size of the zipfile, but going from 3GB down to 2GB sounds like wouldn't be easy.

Comment: I finally ended up by downloading the video assets if I can't find them in the app cache. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, @Michael Burr led me to the answer. Bundling big assets (videos, around 3Go) wasn't a good idea in the first place. As long as I wasn't installing this app through the Play Store, I didn't think that would be an issue, but it is.

I did remove these assets from my bundle, and made a simple function to check if the files exists in the devices cache, and if not, download them, using `react-native-fs`.

**In a nutshell, don't bundle huge assets in your app.**

Answer (score -1):

In your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file, add `android:largeHeap="true"` into `<application .../>` section as below :

```xml
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  ...
  ...
  android:largeHeap="true">

  ...
  ...
</application>
```

This will increase the heap memory size so, memory issue will not occure.

Comment: Actually, it did not work. As far as I understand, largeHeap is used so the running app can request a larger amount of memory on the device, which is not what I need: allocating more memory to build an apk of the app.

Answer (score -1):

In your android/gradle.properties file. Add this line
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError